# Using inheritance inside struct

Tags: inheritance

**EDITED**

Thanks to Marc Gravell answer and to the other, now is working:

```
public class INFO_BASE{

};

public class INFO_INHE : INFO_BASE {...};

class DATA{
   //stuff
   public INFO_BASE info;
};


DATA foo = new DATA();
//.......do things.........//
data.info = new INFO_INHE();
```

i couldn't say why i was focused with use structs instead of classes, you all are right, my apologizes, thanks for your help.

Comment: Why use a struct? I think you need the full OO functionality that classes provide

Comment: I'm not sure what your trying to do here but your code will not compile.  You can't inherit from a struct, there's no such thing as a virtual constructor, and you can't add a parameterless constructor to a struct.

Comment: You can not use inheritance with `structs` in C#. Structures are sealed and can only implement interfaces. I'm not sure how you've gotten your code to compile.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. There will be different INFO_INHE objects, with different internal structs. I will receive a message from an UDP socket with data and inside of it one of that INHE structs and what i'm trying to do is use the same struct for every udp messages overriding the info field

Comment: @Nak why are you thinking `struct`? What is the though process that has led you to choose `struct` here? I strongly suspect it is simply a bad choice.

Comment: for info, it is often a bad idea to edit the question too heavily after-the-fact; it may make the answers hard to understand in the updated context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Till here everything is ok,

No, it really isn't. **Nothing** so far is OK.

However, I think you simply want classes here:

```
class InfoBase { }

class InfoInhe : InfoBase { }

class Data
{
    public InfoBase Info { get;set; }
}
```

then:

```
Data foo = new Data();
//.......do things.........//
foo.Info = new InfoInhe();
```

It is **very** rare that you need to create a `struct` in C#, and most times I see it in "here's my code" samples, it is being used inappropriately.

Comment: so freaking time wasted with structs and classes was the point.... ok, i think i need a rest. BIG THANKS

Comment: @MarcGravell Structs have interesting properties though, such as structural equality (when they are not composed of reference types) and non nullability. This makes them good candidates for value objects if you're willing to ignore their other flaws http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucabol/archive/2007/12/24/creating-an-immutable-value-object-in-c-part-iii-using-a-struct.aspx

Comment: @guillaume31 any type *can* have structural equality; as for non-nullability: that is rarely one of the biggest hurdles in real code

Comment: Yes, I was talking about inherent properties, not ones that you have to program.

Comment: About nullability : some have called that a billion dollar mistake ;)

Answer (score 0):

Structures in C# can only implement interfaces.

```
Structs can also contain constructors, constants, fields, methods, properties, indexers,
operators, events, and nested types, although if several such members are required, 
you should consider making your type a class instead.
```

Structures are meant for grouping data together, as a general rule, if you need methods / contrsucts, your better of with a class. [As per this [Link](http://csharp.2000things.com/2013/01/28/767-a-struct-is-implicitly-sealed/) structures are sealed, they cannot be inherited, so your code will not compile. I'd recommend using classes instead. ]

Comment: The "if you need methods" is IMO very bad and misleading advice; whether or not you need methods is largely **completely unrelated** to whether it should be a struct or a class. Usually, when I see people say that - they are coming from a C/C++ background. Which is different. Things that might suggest `struct` are the intersection of: "represents a *value* rather than an *entity*", "immutable", and "small". Nothing whatsoever about methods.